# Babel gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '' of null

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm stuck with this error that I'm getting in babel:
UnCaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'term' of null This is happening as I'm passing the state of the component into the playlists prop of the Playlist child component.

```
class PlaylistSearchBar extends React.Component{

constuctor(){
    super();
    const initialState = {
         term: {tracks: [], playlists: []}
    }

    this.state = {
         ...initialState
    };
}

return(
        <div>
            <div className="main">
                    <div className="ui massive icon input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a song or artist..." className="js-search input-search"/>
                        <i className="search icon js-submit"></i>
                    </div>
                    <button onclick={localStorageClear()} className="clear">Clear Playlist</button>
            </div>

            <div className="search-results js-search-results ui cards">

            </div>
Error here at term  --> <Playlist playlists = {this.state.term.playlists} setTracksToNil = {this.setState({tracks: []})} embedItems = {this.getEmbed}/>
           </div>
    );
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you need to call `super()` in your constructor before you use `this`

Comment: there are also issues in your JSX - you are using `class` instead of `className` and your button `onclick` is regular HTML

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. However, I'm getting a new error that makes no sense to me. I posted the attachment above.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: you have a typo, `constuctor` instead of `constructor`

Comment: This was embarrasing. Thanks.

Comment: we have all been there - don't sweat it

Comment: this should be closed because its a typographical error?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of errors, constructor was misspelled, and you didn't include a render function.

```
class PlaylistSearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const initialState = {
      term: { tracks: [], playlists: [] }
    }
    this.state = {
      ...initialState
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="main">
          <div className="ui massive icon input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search for a song or artist..." className="js-search input-search" />
            <i className="search icon js-submit"></i>
          </div>
          <button onclick={localStorageClear()} className="clear">Clear Playlist</button>
        </div>

        <div className="search-results js-search-results ui cards">

        </div>
        <Playlist playlists={this.state.term.playlists} setTracksToNil={this.setState({ tracks: [] })} embedItems={this.getEmbed} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```